# a null error while mapping lists with widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

so i have been learning about flutter and i tried making this demo app while at it and faced this "The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: MyAppState#e9765):
Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type 'Null'
" error while i was mapping the lists with widgets so any help would be appreciated a lot

ps: i got a feeling i made a silly mistake when i was mapping the answers tho pls see if its right too

here is the main

```
import 'package:demo_flutter/answer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import 'answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int no = 0;
  var qIndex = 0;

  void questionanswered() {
    setState(() {
      qIndex++;
    });
    print(qIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {
        //maps identifier inside a list
        'questionText': 'which anime do you prefer',
        'answersText': [
          'Naruto',
          'One Punch Man',
          'my hero acadamea',
          'one piece',
          'death note',
          'Attack on titan',
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'which one do you think is the worst',
        'answerText': [
          'agamme ga kill',
          'nanatsu no taizai',
          'mob psycho',
          'fairy tale',
          'bleach',
          'tokyo ghoul',
        ],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'how much animes did you see till today',
        'answerText': [
          'less than 10',
          'less than 30',
          'less than 70',
          'less than 100',
          'more than 100'
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'how mich hours did you spent enjoying them',
        'answerText': [
          'less than week = 168 hrs',
          'less than month =730.001 hrs',
          'less than 3 months =2190 hrs',
          'less than 8 months =5840.01hrs',
          'more than 8 months'
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'do you regret being a fan',
        'answerText': ['nop never', 'i really do', 'maybe', 'i dunno ...']
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'do you read manga',
        'answerText': ['yes', 'nop']
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'which genere interests you',
        'answerText': [
          'Shōnen Manga: Comics for young teenage boys',
          'Shōjo Manga: Comics for young teenage girls',
          'Seinen Manga: Comics for young adult males',
          'Seijin Manga: Adult comics for males',
          'Redisu (Lady’s) Manga: Comics for young adult females',
          'Dōjinshi Manga: Comic publication that’s written by and for amateurs',
          'Gekiga Manga: Comics focusing on serious topics geared toward mature audiences'
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'how much hours do you think u spent reading them',
        'answerText': [
          'less than week = 168 hrs',
          'less than month =730.001 hrs',
          'less than 3 months =2190 hrs',
          'less than 8 months =5840.01hrs',
          'more than 8 months'
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'do you like reading web novels',
        'answerText': ['yes', 'no']
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'if you do how much did u read',
        'answerText': [
          'less than 10',
          'less than 30',
          'less than 70',
          'less than 100',
          'more than 100'
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'which genere interests you',
        'answerText': [
          'Fantasy',
          'Sci-Fi',
          'Mystery',
          'Thriller',
          'Romance',
          'Westerns',
        ]
      },
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('anime personality check'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              question(questions[qIndex]['questionText'].toString()),
              ...(questions[qIndex]['answerText'] as List<String>)
                  .map((answer) {
                return Answer(questionanswered, answer);
              }).toList()
            ],
          )),
      theme: ThemeData(
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.teal,
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  onSurface: Colors.grey))),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the answer state

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback SHandler;
  final String answerText;
  Answer(this.SHandler, String this.answerText);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 4, 14, 4),
        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: SHandler, child: Text(answerText)));
  }
}
```

and here is the question

```
class question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;
  question(this.questionText);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          questionText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: In your first question inside questions, `answersText` should be `answerText`.

Comment: tnx enzo i didnt notice that

Comment: and it is solved just like that a big  thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `answersText` to `answerText` here:

```
{
        //maps identifier inside a list
        'questionText': 'which anime do you prefer',
        'answersText': [     /// <- here to 'answerText'
          'Naruto',
          'One Punch Man',
          'my hero acadamea',
          'one piece',
          'death note',
          'Attack on titan',
        ]
      },
```